# How was this equation simplified?

Tags: trigonometry

In lecture my professor wrote down this equation and it's solution:
$$A_x^{'}=\sqrt{A_x^2+A_y^2}\cos(\theta +\phi)=A_x^{'}=\sqrt{A_x^2+A_y^2}\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)-\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$$

$$=A_x\cos(\phi)-A_y\sin(\phi)$$

All of the steps are skipped in both lecture and in the textbook. That's the only information given. I've been trying to work out the algebra but it's not happening. I tried squaring both sides, it got very messy, but no matter what I tried I couldn't get it down to the solution given.

I tried using the product to sum of two angles trig identity, but it kept me going in circles. What is the best way to get started on simplifying this?

Comment: It follows from $\cos(\theta +\phi)=\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)-\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)$, except you are missing some parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac{A_{x}}{\sqrt{(A_{x})^{2}+(A_{y})^{2}}
}\leq1 $$ $ So, if $\cos(\theta)$ is set to $\frac{A_{x}}{\sqrt{(A_{x})^{2}+(A_{y})^{2}}
}$, then it's not hard to see that $\sin(\theta)=\frac{A_{y}}{\sqrt{(A_{x})^{2}+(A_{y})^{2}}}$. Thus,$\sqrt{(A_{x})^{2}+(A_{y})^{2}}(\cos(\theta)\cos(\phi)-\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi))$ reduces to $A_{x}\cos(\phi)-A_{y}\sin(\phi)$.